# Automatic reload UiLabel Data

Tags: ios, uilabel, parse-platform, reloaddata

in my view controller I have a label that has the function of counter data that are invoked by a PFQuery from Parse.com .. these data may change at any time.

I need this label is updated automatically when the data changes in databrowser even if the user is not sailing in the app.

Let's say that I would need some kind of automatic reload of the label as to the TableView. How can I do? Does anyone know the correct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, assume that you have a `pfLabel` in your cell.

Implement your query in the following delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
 ..................
 // Do stuff here.
 PFQuery *yourQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YOUR_PARSE_CLASS_NAME"];
 // Implement your query constraint here, after that, get your desired data and show it using your desired label
[yourQuery findObjecsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSString* obj) {
    pfLabel.text = obj;
}];
// Congrat, you just have your label asynchronously showed your parse data.
.....................
}
```

Comment: Babygau Hello, I thank you once again for your help ... My label is not internal to a cell but in the viewDidAppear method is aggunta on the Navigation bar.

I tried to enter the query in viewDidAppear but after findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock soon as I plug (NSString *) as you suggested, the code gives me an error ... Surely I'm wrong but I would like to understand where I'm wrong: D ...

Comment: I think you should have got prob with your query, do you mind sharing your codes? or use NSLog to check the data type of the returned object from Parse

Comment: NSLog I have not inserted because the error stops me the code and I do not even by way of making the run ... The only way to call the findinbackgroun with blocks or with the target or with NSArrary

[QueryForUserClass findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: ^ (NSArray * objects, NSError * error) {

Comment: `findInBackgroundWithBlocks` is a `callback block` which is invoked when the query completed or error. You cannot assign an array to a `block`. that might be your prob.

Comment: heheh me to work perfectly when I run the query [QueryForUserClass findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: ^ (NSArray * objects, NSError * error) {

as the classic Query which is located on the documentation parse ... What then as I said in my first post the problem is not that I do not receive data is that the data did not refresh the page every specific time

  example every 5 minutes a refresh of UIView and all its query

Comment: @rory is it related to your other questions??? as I'm helping you in other question as well.

Comment: Yes, yes I read the other question ... and I realized my stupid mistake! : D
For this question, it's like I said I need that the view can update the data continuously or with a timer every 5 minutes ... Refresh data view of the whole and all its queries, not only of the Tableview

Comment: You can get your data refreshed after every 5 minutes because that's long enough for your datasource get updated but not the latest one as I mentioned in other post, it's because you refresh your tableview before datasource get updated. Now I think all should be set, right :)

Comment: Okkappa I make some test and I inform you: D

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look at ReactiveCocoa & RAC-ParseExtensions. They will absolutely blow your mind